# How to tell self hosted Windows pipeline runner to skip the cleanup routine of a build step

Tags: yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

I am troubleshooting a git issue with self hosted runner on windows. I feel it is lot easier if the runner leaves behind cloned dir as it is instead of cleaning it up.

Wondering if there is any YML directive or some other setting to tell runner to disable cleanup step.

Thanks